# How to Prove the Fourier Transform of Vertical Line Mathematically?

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, fft

I've tried to do Fourier transform in Matlab of vertical line. I make matrix A with a 100x100 size, and pass the value 1s in certain number of column vector, whereas the others is 0s.

Here is the script (you can see the plot result in the screenshot below):

```
A = zeros(100,100);
A(:,10)=1;
A_FFT = abs(fft2(A));
figure, imshow(A,[]);
title('vertical line (A)');
figure, imshow(A_FFT,[]);
title('FFT of Vertical Line (A)');
```

From the result, I get horizontal line matrix A_FFT(u,v) which is A_FFT(1,:)=100 and the other matrix components are 0s. From the theory, yes, I can understand why the result is like that. But, I need to prove it mathematically. I have tried to write and solve the DFT equation of matrix A, but still don't get the right result. Can anyone help me how to prove this mathematically ?

Screenshot:

[image: img]

left : original vertical line, matrix A; right : DFT of A, by taking fft2

Comment: Not sure this is the right forum for discussing mathematical proofs of this nature, math.stackexchange.com would be better.  But, to give you a hint in the direction you need to go, let f(x,y) = 1 and then plug it into the definition of the 2D Fourier Transform.  In this case, the result will use the Dirac delta function.

Comment: Yes, the DFT of 1 will be diract delta function. I will try to calculate again..

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal transform gives values (proportional to)

```
exp(i * (2*pi)/100 *10*k)
```

while the vertical transform (of constant values along the columns) sets all coefficients to zero except the zeroth one.

Since

```
abs(exp(i*whateverreal)) == 1
```

you get a solid white horizontal line.